# android SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy") not working well

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat

I have this function

```
private void setDateInTopBar() {
        Date bodyPartDate = DataManager.instance().getSelectedBodyPart().getPublicationDate();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
        String formattedDate = format.format(bodyPartDate);
        TextView dateTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtImageDate);
        dateTxt.setText(formattedDate);
    }
```

but my month is 0, when day and year is working well, what's the problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Replace:

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
```

With:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

as `mm` referes to minutes.. check http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 3):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

lower-case m is for minutes.

Try: "dd/MM/yyyy"

Answer (score 2):

I should set `MM` not `mm` here

`SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");`

Answer (score 2):

`mm`  means Minutes, So you shouldn't use it for Month, change `mm` to `MM`.
Your code must be like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Instead of this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
```

You can read all about these letters [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)